# Change Shipping Method Name programmatically

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, programmatically

i want to change the Shipping Method Name programmatically in some cases.
[image]

*(This store is in german)*

So I want to change "Versand oder Abholung" to another different text depending on the case.

How can I manipulate this text?

I have found the .html file which contains this div. (Maybe this will help?)
*app\design\frontend\MyStore\MyStoreTheme\Magento_Checkout\web\shipping.html*

```
<form class="form methods-shipping" id="co-shipping-method-form" data-bind="submit: setShippingInformation" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div id="checkout-shipping-method-load">
                <table class="table-checkout-shipping-method">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Select Method'"></th>
                            <th class="col col-price" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></th>
                            <th class="col col-method" data-bind="i18n: 'Method Title'"></th>
                            <th class="col col-carrier" data-bind="i18n: 'Carrier Title'"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
```

...
...
...

```
<td class="col col-method" data-bind="text: method.method_title, attr: {'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code}"></td>
```

Any ideas? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have found a solution.

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

    class Tablerate extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate
    {
        public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
        {
            $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create()
            $method = $this->_resultMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setMethod('bestway');
            $method->setMethodTitle("test1234");
            $result->append($method);
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate"
            type="Dicode\Shipping\Model\Carrier\OverrideTablerate" />


<?php
/**
 * @author Moazzam ALi
 * Created by PhpStorm
 * User: moazzam
 * Date: 4/10/22
 * Time: 11:41 PM
 */

namespace Dicode\Shipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Tablerate;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

/**
 * Override the createShipmentMethod to change the shiping rate name
 *
 * Class OverrideTablerate
 */
class OverrideTablerate extends Tablerate
{
    /**
     * Collect rates.
     *
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        // exclude Virtual products price from Package value if pre-configured
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('include_virtual_price') && $request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $child->getBaseRowTotal());
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                    $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $item->getBaseRowTotal());
                }
            }
        }

        // Free shipping by qty
        $freeQty = 0;
        $freePackageValue = 0;

        if ($request->getAllItems()) {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                            $freeShipping = is_numeric($child->getFreeShipping()) ? $child->getFreeShipping() : 0;
                            $freeQty += $item->getQty() * ($child->getQty() - $freeShipping);
                        }
                    }
                } elseif ($item->getFreeShipping() || $item->getAddress()->getFreeShipping()) {
                    $freeShipping = $item->getFreeShipping() ?
                        $item->getFreeShipping() : $item->getAddress()->getFreeShipping();
                    $freeShipping = is_numeric($freeShipping) ? $freeShipping : 0;
                    $freeQty += $item->getQty() - $freeShipping;
                    $freePackageValue += $item->getBaseRowTotal();
                }
            }

            $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValue() - $freePackageValue);
            $request->setPackageValueWithDiscount($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() - $freePackageValue);
        }

        if (!$request->getConditionName()) {
            $conditionName = $this->getConfigData('condition_name');
            $request->setConditionName($conditionName ? $conditionName : $this->_defaultConditionName);
        }

        // Package weight and qty free shipping
        $oldWeight = $request->getPackageWeight();
        $oldQty = $request->getPackageQty();

        $request->setPackageWeight($request->getFreeMethodWeight());
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty - $freeQty);

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
        $rate = $this->getRate($request);

        $request->setPackageWeight($oldWeight);
        $request->setPackageQty($oldQty);

        if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
            if ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty) {
                $shippingPrice = 0;
            } else {
                $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($rate['price']);
            }
            $method = $this->createShippingMethod($shippingPrice, $rate['cost']);
            $result->append($method);
        } elseif ($request->getPackageQty() == $freeQty) {

            /**
             * Promotion rule was applied for the whole cart.
             *  In this case all other shipping methods could be omitted
             * Table rate shipping method with 0$ price must be shown if grand total is more than minimal value.
             * Free package weight has been already taken into account.
             */
            $request->setPackageValue($freePackageValue);
            $request->setPackageQty($freeQty);
            $rate = $this->getRate($request);
            if (!empty($rate) && $rate['price'] >= 0) {
                $method = $this->createShippingMethod(0, 0);
                $result->append($method);
            }
        } else {
            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error $error */
            $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => [
                        'carrier' => $this->_code,
                        'carrier_title' => $this->getConfigData('title'),
                        'error_message' => $this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'),
                    ],
                ]
            );
            $result->append($error);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Get rate.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     * @return array|bool
     */
    public function getRate(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->_tablerateFactory->create()->getRate($request);
    }

    /**
     * Get code.
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @param string $code
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function getCode($type, $code = '')
    {
        $codes = [
            'condition_name' => [
                'package_weight' => __('Weight vs. Destination'),
                'package_value_with_discount' => __('Price vs. Destination'),
                'package_qty' => __('# of Items vs. Destination'),
            ],
            'condition_name_short' => [
                'package_weight' => __('Weight (and above)'),
                'package_value_with_discount' => __('Order Subtotal (and above)'),
                'package_qty' => __('# of Items (and above)'),
            ],
        ];

        if (!isset($codes[$type])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('The "%1" code type for Table Rate is incorrect. Verify the type and try again.', $type)
            );
        }

        if ('' === $code) {
            return $codes[$type];
        }

        if (!isset($codes[$type][$code])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('The "%1: %2" code type for Table Rate is incorrect. Verify the type and try again.', $type, $code)
            );
        }

        return $codes[$type][$code];
    }

    /**
     * Get allowed shipping methods
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return ['bestway' => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * Get the method object based on the shipping price and cost
     *
     * @param float $shippingPrice
     * @param float $cost
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method
     */
    private function createShippingMethod($shippingPrice, $cost)
    {
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_resultMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->getCarrierCode());
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod('bestway');
        if ($shippingPrice <= 3.95 ){
            $customMethodName = 'First Class Mail';
            $method->setMethodTitle($customMethodName);
        }elseif ($shippingPrice <= 10.95){
            $customMethodName = 'Priority Mail';
            $method->setMethodTitle($customMethodName);
        }elseif ($shippingPrice >= 14.95){
            $customMethodName = 'Priority Mail larger boxes';
            $method->setMethodTitle($customMethodName);
        }else{
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        }
        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($cost);
        return $method;
    }
}
```